# Resources for learning the Silbo Gomero (Gomeran Whistle)

Tags: learning-methods, resource-request, self-learning, spanish

[Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgEmSb0cKBg) a fascinating video on the *Silbo Gomero*, or whistled tongue of the island of Gomera in the Canary Islands of Spain. Today, it's essentially used as an encoding of Spanish that can be carried for long distances - more analogous to Leetspeak (73h 1337n3553 5p34|<5g3) and Braille than an independent language, but still linguistically very interesting.

Assuming I already speak Spanish well enough, are there any resources that specifically teach the whistled tongue? The video does mention that it is now being taught in schools, so a pedagogy must exist, but it is unclear if it is still something that you *have* to learn from another speaker (whistler?) or whether or not you can pick it up from books or videos.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing Spanish will help you to read some resources, but may not help you with this language unless somehow the messages are sent word for word in Spanish.  It looks like it's mainly used to send public messages, so you don't need a cell phone or email on this island. :)

A professional whistler may help you with the training in forming your mouth for the whistles.

I found [one site that teaches it.](https://www.busuu.com/en/silbo)

[Here's another that has multiple resources](http://silbo-gomero.com/links.html) some of which are in Spanish.